# Proving convexity of constraint having squared Euclidean norm

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I know that $||x||^2_2$ is a convex function. I want to check if the following constraint is convex.

$$\sum^N_i \alpha_i -\sum^N_i \frac{||\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{z}||_2^2}{\beta} \alpha_i  \leq constant $$

Where, $\beta > 0$ is contant, $\alpha_i's$ are constant can be both negative and positive, $\mathbf{x}_i's \in \mathbb{R}^n $ are constant vectors and $\mathbf{z}\in \mathbb{R}^n $  is variable.

Is there any established convex relaxation if it is not convex?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Just take $N=1, \alpha _1=1=\beta$ and $x_1=0$.

Comment: Is there any relaxation for the same?

Comment: @ParikshitPareek Basically the minus sign in the second term converts convexity to concavity.

Comment: That means $$ \sum^N_i \alpha_i -\sum^N_i \frac{||\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{z}||_2^2}{\beta} \alpha_i \geq constant $$  can be converted into convex by shifitng terms but $\leq constant$ cannot be.

Comment: @ParikshitPareek Yes, that is right.

Comment: What if the original $\leq constant $ constraint is placed in the objective of the problem? As it is concave, maxima should be easy to get and minimas are at the boundary values of $\mathbf{z}$ intuitively.